# How to read a slack user ID from response and get the username ,

Tags: python, httprequest, slack-api

I need to get all the details from a slack channel and dump it in a simple text file. I am able to get the information using :

```
payload = {'token': 'XXXXXX', 'channel': 'XXXXXX' , 'count': '10'}
r = requests.get('https://slack.com/api/channels.history', params=payload)
pprint(r.json())
k = r.json()for msg in k['messages']:
    print msg['text']   # this extracts the text field from json
```

This gets me the response in json which looks like:

```
{u'has_more': False,
 u'is_limited': True,
 u'messages': [{u'text': u'This is not a test!',
                u'ts': u'1459763505.000003',
                u'type': u'message',
                u'user': u'U03FE3Z7D'},
               {u'subtype': u'bot_message',
                u'text': u'This is a test!',
                u'ts': u'1459750060.000002',
                u'type': u'message',
                u'username': u'facsimile_test'}],
 u'ok': True}

    This is not a test!
    This is a test!
```

This is good stuff for me.. but not worth until i get to know the username also. I am intersted in passing the userid to slack web API and getting the name and after that dumping the whole messages in a text file as

```
-- username1
      - messages
-- username2
      - message
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? It is not very clear what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: i am actually not sure how to get the username from the userid , so i don't have the code

Answer (score 4):

Slack provides an [API endpoint](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info) to get a users info using the user id:

```
payload = {'token': 'XXXXXX', 'user': 'XXXXXX'}
r = requests.get('https://slack.com/api/users.info', params=payload)
```

And, from here you can get the `name` field from the response which is the `username` in-fact.

If you don't want to get this information for individual users, you could get the [`users.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list) as well. And then create a mapping between the `userid` and `username` so you could access it wheneven you want to.

Comment: how to map this the `userid` and `username` i am basically confused where i am getting the userid and i read the userid from it and send a request to slack for username, then print the username and corresponding usermessage

Answer (score -2):

What you got there is a python dictionary, not json.

Try using `requests` to send request with user's auth info.

```
resp = requests.get("http://yourslackapiendpoint", auth=("user", "password"))
data = resp.json()
# unmarshal JSON to a dict
d = json.loads(data)

# loop the dictionary and write to a file
```

If Slack API requires a different auth (which is likely), see how to pass parameters on the [requests doc](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/).